# Confusion about a proof of Jordan Holder theorem

Tags: group-theory

[image]

[image]

This proof is in Aluffi's algebra chapter $0$.

Why the composition series of $K$ exist? I can't see it.Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Sorry..Dose the induction hypothesis imply anything about existence?I don't understand yet..

Comment: Right, not by induction, but because $K\unlhd G$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:  If $G$ has a composition series and $K \unlhd G$ is normal, then $K$ has a composition series (whose length is no greater than that of the given composition series of $G$).   To see this, consider the series obtained by intersecting $K$ with the given composition series for $G$.  This is not necessarily a composition series, but it is close.